# What is the operator= returning?

Tags: c++, reference

Came across a code. I am posting the snippet.

```
Animal & Animal::operator=(const Animal & o) {
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
    if(this != &o) {
        _type = o._type;
        _name = clone_prefix + o._name;
        _sound = o._sound;
    }
    return *this;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    Animal a;
    a.print();

    const Animal b("goat", "bob", "baah");
    b.print();

    const Animal c = b;
    c.print();

    a = c;
    a.print();

    return 0;
```

---

My question: This is he pointer to the current object right? The assignment operator returns the object of Animal type right? since it is returning *this?  But isn't it supposed to return address of object since its return type is Animal & ?
I am not understanding this.

Comment: It's the same reason you don't do `a = &c` for the reference  parameter.

Comment: You would return the address if it were declared `Animal*`. A reference is not the same as a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator=` returns an `Animal&`, i.e. a reference to an `Animal`. Maybe your confusion stems from the fact that `&` is also used to take the address of an object, i.e. to produce a pointer to an object. As a type modifier, it means "reference". So `*this` is correct.

Think about this code snippet:

```
Animal a{}; //suppose Animal has a default constructor
Animal& b = a;
Animal* c = &a;
Animal& d = *c;
```

`a` is the actual object, whereas `b` is a reference to `a` (not a pointer, so `a` goes on the right-hand side and not the address of `a`). `c` is a pointer to `a`, so we assign it the *address* of `a` with `&a` on the right-hand side. `d` is also a reference to `a`, but instead of just assigning `a` to it, we dereference the pointer `c` (completely equivalent to the second line). Imagine `this` instead of `c` and the return value of the function instead of `d` and you have `return *this`.

General note: It is a well-known idiom and a useful convention that `operator=` returns a reference of the assigned-to object, because it mimics the behavior of primitive types. However, chaining of assignments like

```
a = b = c
```

would also be possible if it returned by value (i.e. `Animal` instead of `Animal&`). However, this would create an extra copy (at least theoretically, if the compiler cannot optimize it away for some reason). No matter how you do it, returning by value or reference makes the above statement possible, whereas returning a pointer wouldn't. Users of your class would be really confused if the `operator=` returned a pointer to an `Animal`, i.e. an `Animal*`.